# how to write ajax function for calling the procedure page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to call this sample.php page using ajax

```
$server1 = "localhost"; //Your MySQL Server
$user1 = "root"; //Your MySQL username
$pass1 = ""; //Password
$dbname1 = "test";
$conn1 = mysql_connect($server1, $user1, $pass1) or die(mysql_error());                            
$db1 = mysql_select_db($dbname1, $conn1) or die(mysql_error());
echo $result = mysql_query($conn1, " CALL users($id)"));
```

I don't know how to write the ajax function call the sample.php

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML page add this code. If you need to pass some parameters then add in `{ id: id }`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sample.php",
  data: { id: id }
})
  .done(function( result) {
    alert( "Response: " + result);
  });
```

Docs Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sample.php",//url of the page where the request is to be send
    type: "POST",//request type get or post
    data: { },//if any data is to send with the request
    success:function(res){
      //Do something if you have to do anything on success
    }
  });
```

You can see the **[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** for more

Comment: now i add the code in main it will call the sample php or not

Comment: What you mean by main.?

Comment: i write the coding to show the value in table format and then i call the sample.php onclick function